# Shared field in composite primary key for foreign keys

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have 4 tables in my database:

```
+-------------+
|Libraries    |
+-------------+ . . . . . _________
|P code       |                   |
+-------------+                   -
      .                           ^
      .                  +---------------+
      |                  |Persons        |
      |                  +---------------+
      -                  |P  name        |
      ^                  |FP library_code|
+-----------------+      +---------------+
|Books            |              .
+-----------------+              .
|P   title        |              |
|FP  library_code |              |
+-----------------+              -
      .                          ^
      .                 +----------------+  
      |                 |Borrows         |
      +_______________|<+----------------+
                        |FP person_name  |
                        |FP book_title   |
                        |FP library_code |
                        +----------------+

P - primary key
FP - foreign primary key

_
^ - foreign key is part of primary key
```

For `Persons` and `Books` column *library_code* in `Borrows` should be the same (shared column)!

My java code looks like:

```
@Entity
class Library {
    @Id
    private String code;
}

@Embeddable
class PersonId implements Serializable {
    private String name;
    private String library_code;
}

@Entity 
class Person {
    @EmbeddedId 
    private PersonId id;
}

@Embeddable
class BookId implements Serializable {
    private String title;
    private String library_code;
}

@Entity 
class Book {
    @EmbeddedId 
    private BookId id;
}
```

**Is it possible to implement `Borrow` entity like this with the shared *library_code* column for `PersonId` and `BookId`, how?**:

```
@Embeddable
class BorrowId implements Serializable {
    private PersonId person;
    private BookId book;
}

@Entity 
class Borrow {
    @EmbeddedId 
    private BorrowId id;
}
```

Note: this question is not about database model, the model is already provided and I can't change it, I just need find the best way how to map it to entity model.

Comment: Given that your PK for `Borrow` is 3 columns rather than 4 (which your embeddable implementation implies), I wouldn't map it that way.  I would just create an embeddable the 3 columns for `Borrow` and copy the values as needed into it without trying to be fancy.

Comment: @Naros we left is as back-up option. We decided that for our application it'll be better to create structure like described in the question.

Comment: You can try using `@AttributeOverride` on one of the inner embeddables to mark the `library_code` as `updatable=false,insertable=false` but I'm not sure if that will end up being sufficient for the persistence provider not to complain about the duplicate column name.  Certain aspects of identifiers do get overridden by some providers (e.g.. not being null) because it makes no sense for a PK column to be null.

Comment: @Naros we'll use your solution, because we didn't find the better one. But I still will be waiting here for an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you first could leverage `@AttributeOverride` here

```
@Embeddable
public class BorrowId implements Serializable {
  private PersonId person;
  @AttributeOverride(
    name = "library_code",
    column = @Column(insertable=false, updatable=false) )
  private BookId book;
  // getter/setter(s) with proper equals/hashcode
}
```

Another option you could consider takes a page out of Domain-Driven Design:

```
@Embeddable
public class BorrowId implements Serializable {
  private String person;
  private String book;
  private String libraryCode;

  // Required by JPA
  // notice its package private
  BorrowId() {}

  public BorrowId(PersonId person, BookId book) {
    // validates you are pairing a person and book with same library codes
    assert person.getLibraryCode().equals( book.getLibraryCode() );
    this.person = person.getName();
    this.book = book.getTitle();
    this.libraryCode = person.getLibraryCode();
  }

  // expose all getters as public 
  // expose all setters as non-public 
  // implement proper equals/hashcode
}
```

The idea with the latter solution here is that we use domain driven design to force the only way to construct a `BorrowId` is to provide it with the identifiers of a `Person` and a `Book`, which makes logical sense as the `Person`, `Book`, and `Library` objects must exist prior.

If you really wanted to take this one step farther, the constructor could be

```
public BorrowId(Person person, Book book, Library library) {
  assert library.getCode().equals( person.getId().getLibraryCode() );
  assert library.getCode().equals( book.getId().getLibraryCode() );
  this.person = person.getId().getName();
  this.book = book.getId().getTitle();
  this.library = library.getCode();
}
```

Hibernate will take care of manipulating the code to properly access what it needs from non-public scopes as needed while leaving the restricted scopes to dictate how you are suppose to use the object.